# Адаптивное позиционирование

Tags: css, position, позиционирование

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеется вот такой блок (на фото), кот находится на заднем фоне и когда наводишь на видео он появляется (поварачивается под определенным углом), как мне правильно разместить кота чтобы он находился на одном месте и адаптивно ?

Спасибо.

Comment: Позиция в процентах, держать соотношение сторон

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, так

```css
.block-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 100px;
}

.block {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}

.block-red {
  position: absolute;
  right: -50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 1
}
```

```html
<div class="block-container">
  <div class="block"></div> <!-- блок с видео -->
  <div class="block-red"></div> <!-- блок с котом -->
</div>
```